# I think I got a badge by mistake

Tags: support, badges

I got the steward badge twice for reviewing the closure queue.

[image: A screenshot showing that I got the Steward badge twice for Close Votes.]

I enjoy getting them as much as Muttley does, but I want to earn them fairly. I thought it was given only once per queue, and even if it isn't, it should take me 2,000 reviews, no? I only did 1,138 so far.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Same here on WB.se and EL&U.se They've both been retracted now however, so presumably it's all sorted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the rules are being changed; you're getting one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a queue. See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1201991_360194) by Stack Exchange staff member @animuson:

> There's supposedly an announcement about review updates coming out today, if it hasn't been published somewhere yet. Seems the code is getting ahead of itself.

However, there seems to be a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1202005_360194), that's why you have two of them even with 1,138 reviews:

> This is my bug, caused by a temporary issue with and old batch job running after a migration took place. I have a fix I can roll out in a few.